# Is it possible to disable flattern in npm3

Tags: node.js, npm

The nmp3 has a new feature — it is reordering entire node_modules without asking. This flattern produces problems in my project. Can I disable this bugofeature?

Thanx

Comment: The *entire point* of NPM is that your project use modules without having to be concerned with the folder structure, so that you only ever need one copy of a particular module.  If your project is referencing nested modules then you aren't using NPM correctly;  If your modules are referencing nested modules, then the modules aren't doing it correctly.

Comment: I am not doing nested require()'s. But such structure is unfriednly for navigation and I can't commit such huge change to existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot disable flattening in npm3 ([source](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9809#issuecomment-151379167)), but you can install npm@2 and use that instead, if you wish.

Comment: npm install -g npm@2.15.8